# Color 2D density plot not by count in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a 2D density plot/levelplot, but instead of coloring by the count, color by another aesthetic. I created a basic scatter plot with geom_point, but I think a density/heatmap/levelplot is more appropriate. When I created a levelplot, it was empty/not populating. There is about 200,000 data points, but I created a small code sample, which works, but I am confused as why it does not work when there are a large number of data points. The x range is from -1.5 to 1.5, y range from 0,5, and z range from 0.5 to 1.5.

```
x<-c(0.77,0.07,0.14,0.07,-0.3,-.45)
y<-c(2.13,2.06,2.38,2.54,1.99,2.45)
z<-c(1.07,1.04,1.18,1.232,0.99,0.75)
s<-data.frame(x,y,z)
levelplot(z ~ x*y, data=s  ,xlab="X",main="")
```

Then with geom_bin2d. How do I adjust this code to color by z rather than by count?

```
ggplot(s, aes(x=x, y=y, color=z),shape=19 ) +
  geom_bin2d(bins = 30) +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something more like: `ggplot(s, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z)) + stat_summary_2d(bins = 5, fun="mean") + scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") + theme_bw()`

Comment: Is that levelplot from the lattice package?

Comment: @JonSpring Yes I believe so.

Comment: @MrFlick That worked. Feel free to post as an answer.